# How to pass variable as input in pxssh

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I am using pxssh to connect with another host and read a file using python.I am able to successfully connect and pass simple commands.How to read a file using cat command where filepath is stored in a variable

```
s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.login(hostname,username,pwd)
path = "mydir/mysubdir/a.txt"
s.sendline('cat ') # How to pass the path variable here
```

Also I want to read the file in line by line manner.Is there any way to do it using cat or any other command or how to do it using python commands.

Answer (score 0):

you can create string and pass like s.sendline(variable)

```
    cmd1 = 'cat '
    path = 'mydir/mysubdir/a.txt'
    cmd = cmd1 + path
    s.sendline(cmd)
    s.prompt()
    file = s.before
    print file.splitlines()[no of line]
```